# Rerun function and save outputs to later plot?

Tags: r, function, loops, tidyverse, frequency

pretty new to R and could use some guidance, help or solutions!

My actual dataset is large so I have this sample dataset with two columns that looks like this:

```
plot<- c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3)
ID<- c("S","S","S","C","T","S","SP","T", "C", "T","S","SP","T","S","C")
dat<- data.frame(plot,ID)
```

I am trying to randomly remove one entry per plot, calculate the frequency of each ID, randomly remove another entry per plot, calculate the frequency and continue repeating.

So far with some help I was able to use the following to randomly remove one entry from each plot

```
dat %>%
  group_by(plot) %>%
  sample_n(n() - 1) %>%
  ungroup()
```

and I was able to use this to calculate the frequency of each ID

```
dat %>%                               
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarise(n = n()) %>%
  mutate(freq = n / sum(n))
```

I need to be able to rinse and repeat these two functions and look at the results each time. This data set is only 15 variables but my actual dataset is a lot larger so it seems inefficient to constantly write it out over 100 times.

Is it possible to loop or rerun both functions together and produce an output each time an x amount of times? For example for the sample data I provided it could be a total of 4 times. I tried "for" loops but I couldn't get it to work (most likely my user error)

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Combine the two operations in one function and use `map` to call it with different `p` values.

```
library(dplyr)

run_sample <- function(dat, p) {
  dat %>%
    group_by(plot) %>%
    sample_n(n() - p) %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    count(ID) %>%
    mutate(freq = n / sum(n))
}

set.seed(123)
purrr::map(seq(n_distinct(dat$ID)), run_sample, dat = dat)
```

This returns a list of tibbles.

```
result

#[[1]]
# A tibble: 4 x 3
#  ID        n  freq
#  <chr> <int> <dbl>
#1 C         2 0.167
#2 S         5 0.417
#3 SP        2 0.167
#4 T         3 0.25 

#[[2]]
# A tibble: 3 x 3
#  ID        n  freq
#  <chr> <int> <dbl>
#1 C         1 0.111
#2 S         6 0.667
#3 T         2 0.222

#[[3]]
# A tibble: 3 x 3
#  ID        n  freq
#  <chr> <int> <dbl>
#1 S         2 0.333
#2 SP        2 0.333
#3 T         2 0.333

#[[4]]
# A tibble: 2 x 3
#  ID        n  freq
#  <chr> <int> <dbl>
#1 C         1 0.333
#2 S         2 0.667
```

Comment: Oh! This almost works!! I think I didn't explain this well. I meant for it to be that everytime it runs another random plot is taken out. SO ti guess the first run would have to be sample_n(n() - 1) and the second run sample_n(n() - 2), then sample_n(n() - 3) and then sample_n(n() - 4)
is that possible to do on there?

Comment: Sorry,  misunderstood your question. Check the updated answer if that's helpful and what you are looking for.

Comment: So it seems like now its going by the amount of unique IDs there are. I changed the dataset to just "S"'s and "T"'s and it only returned two tibbles when it should still be 4. If I had 3 different IDs it returns 3, 4 returns 4 BUT the second you get to 5 unique IDs so some being (S,T,C,SP,R) it cant run because invalid length

Comment: I believe its from the n_distinct

Comment: Yes, in the code now the sequence is generated from 1 to number of unique values in `ID`. I thought that is how you get 4. If that's not the case how do you decide 4?

Comment: I decided 4 because if you take out 5 random points per plot (3 plots) then you have 0 points left.  Does that make sense?

Comment: So if you added one more "S" to each plot it would be 5 cause you would be able to remove 5 random points per plot since at 6 random points per plot it would just be 0. Technically it could go to 0 if that make the code any easier. Or if the code is just remove one random point per plot continuously.

Comment: I don't follow but if you want to hardcode it to 4, you can change `purrr::map(1:4, run_sample, dat = dat)`. Not sure, if that answers your question.

Comment: I see! I changed the seq() to just seq(5) and that seemed to work!

Comment: Yes that works! You are a lifesaver thank you!! FINAL QUESTION: any tips on something I can read or go through to get better at R. That way I can understand what I am coding?

Comment: there is no alternative to practicing and using R everyday to be better at it but if you want to read something you may try https://r4ds.had.co.nz/ . It's a good resource.